# See Generated Query with Phantom

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I am using the phantom cassandra DSL for scala. What I want to do is simple: I want to see and logs the generated queries for every time there's a query.

I can't find anything on [the wiki](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/wiki) or tutorials and searching across the web.

Any help with that? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

At any point in the query you should be able to call `.qb.querystring` to print out the query, this will simply return a string containing the serialisation formed by everything in the chain up until that point.

Phantom is 100% immutable and as a result you will even be able to walk through intermediary stages.

Answer (score 1):

With Phantom 1.22.0 I see in our app all queries in our logs with this entry inside our LogBack.xml:

`<logger name="com.websudos.phantom" level="DEBUG"/>`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if you start your application, phantom writes all queries to your console. You can write this output to a file:

```
sbt 'run' > log
```